# HTTP Error 406 after execting a restsharp request

Tags: c#, json, rest, http, restsharp

I'm trying to use RestSharp to connect to a server. but I get `HTTP Error 406 Not acceptable`.
Here is the web service response:

```
{"metaInfo":{"ErrorString":" ","ErrorCode":" ","Result":true},"userModel":
{"UserId":"123qwe","UserName":"aaa","FirstName":"ALi","LastName":"TbT"}}
```

The rest service is actually a simple php file that I created for test:

```
<?php
$a = array("metaInfo"=>array("ErrorString"=>" ","ErrorCode"=>" ","Result"=>true),"userModel"=>array("UserId"=>"123qwe","UserName"=>"aaa","FirstName"=>"ALi","LastName"=>"TbT"));
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

And Here is the RegisterResult and MetaInfo classes:

```
public class RegisterResult
    {
        public MetaInfo metaInfo { get; set; }
    }
public class MetaInfo
    {
        public string ErrorString { get; set; }
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }
        public bool Result { get; set; }
    }
```

The code that runs the rest request is as follows:

```
var client = new RestClient(Configuration.PortalUri);
var request = new RestRequest(requestUri, HttpMethod.Post);
var asyncHandle = await client.Execute<RegisterResult>(request);
```

Could you please tell me what the problem is? *I think something is wrong with headers or encoding or something like that. Am I right?*

Answer (score 2):

This error is specific to the way the programmers have created the service you are calling.  There's nothing wrong with your code from a C# perspective, but the way the service author has chosen to implement their service doesn't like something in the service call.  You will have to refer to their documentation or ask one of their programmers.

Here's an explanation of http error 406 
(taken from http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E406.html):

> Fixing 406 errors - general
>
> This error occurs very infrequently in Web browsers, because most
>   browsers will accept any data returned from the Web server.
>
> If the client is not a Web browser, then anyone can only investigate
>   the problem by looking at the Accept headers generated by the client
>   system

Consider these headers to modify:

> •Accept: The MIME types accepted by the client. For example, a browser
>   may only accept back types of data (HTML files, GIF files etc.) it
>   knows how to process.
>   •Accept-Charset: The character sets accepted by
>   the client.
>   •Accept-Encoding: The data encoding accepted by the
>   client e.g. the file formats it understands.  •Accept-Language: The
>   natural languages (English, German etc.) accepted by the client. 
>   •Accept-Ranges: Whether the client accepts ranges of bytes from the
>   resource i.e. a portion of the resource.

For example, you may need to add this to your request:

```
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
```

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for your answer. Actually there is no service provider. The `Rest` response is something I myself created in a simple php file. That's a simple array encoded in json format. Could you possibly take a look at the updated question.

Comment: Maybe try this?
request.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. The Problem was that I had written `test` as request Uri but I should've used `test.php` instead! I dont know why it was throwing an unacceptable error code instead of simply throwing a 404 not found message!!